# simple CSS grid with unequal image sizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to layout a list of images in a grid format.

They shall behave like this:

- stretched to 100% of the screen width if viewed on small screens
- stretched to 50% of the screen width if viewed on tablet screens
- stretched to 25% of the screen width if viewed on large desktop screens

I have something very close, but the problem is, the images have different sizes, and therefore the layout is broken. How should I fix the code so that the smaller image will be stretched bigger to match the bigger boxes automatically?

See the problem here:http://jsfiddle.net/Gep2G/embedded/result/

My HTML source code:

```
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'><img src='http://placekitten.com/352/288'/></div>
    <div id='wrapper'><img src='http://placekitten.com/352/288'/></div>
    <div id='wrapper'><img src='http://placekitten.com/352/288'/></div>
    <div id='wrapper'><img src='http://placekitten.com/320/240'/></div>
    <div id='wrapper'><img src='http://placekitten.com/320/240'/></div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0}
img{width:100%;height:100%;}
#wrapper{width:100%;float: left;}   

@media (min-width:320px) {
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    body {margin:0;padding:0}
    img{width:100%;height:100%;}
    #wrapper{width:100%;float: left;}   
}
@media (min-width:961px) { 
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */ 
    body {margin:0;padding:0}
    img{width:100%;height:100%;}
    #wrapper{width:50%;float: left;}    
}
@media (min-width:1025px) { 
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */ 
    body {margin:0;padding:0}
    img{width:100%;height:100%;}
    #wrapper{width:50%;float: left;}    
}
@media (min-width:1281px) { 
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */ 
    body {margin:0;padding:0}
    img{width:100%;height:100%;}
    #wrapper{width:25%;float: left;}    
}
```

Editable code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gep2G/

Comment: but this will distort your images

Comment: Ya... I wonder is there anyway to stretch the smaller images in proportion to match the bigger images..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its a simple fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gep2G/4/embedded/result/

```
img{width:100%; hieght:352px;}
```

As long as you specify only one dimension: the browser will auto fill the image in the correct proportion. Continue to set the height as desired for each media query.

Additionally there were a few errors in your css. For example an id should only be applied to a single element. Use classes for multiple elements ( like your wrapper element).

Comment: but by setting a height... the image may get stretched horizontally...hmm.. (thanks for pointing out the mistakes..)

Comment: as long as you set you image height proportionally at each media query the image wont be distorted. its a little manually intensive, but is easier to implement than the li overflow trick.

Answer (score 0):

i made a script to solve this issue before :

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/QD9kZ/

```
side1=0,side2=0

$(".flexbox").children().each(function(index, element) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) //odd children (starts with 0 )
    {
$(this).css("top",side1+"px") 
side1+=parseInt($(this).css("height"))
    }
else //even children
    {
$(this).css("top",side2+"px")
$(this).css("left","50%") 
side2+=parseInt($(this).css("height"))
    }   
});
```

but if you want pure css solution i would recommend checking  : 
http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/
the pure css solution.

Comment: the demo looks like it will distort the image too?

Comment: indeed , any solution will distort your image because you are stretching it !! the best solution is to sort them correctly ( because they have different dimensions ) , and that was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1281px){
#wrapper {
width: 25%;
float: left;
height: 20em;
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't really meet my requirement that the width of the image has to fill the screen dynamically. (100%, 50%, 25%...)